# When to provide error control for mysqli queries (PHP)

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, database-connection

Okay, so I have some code here:

```
<?php

$rt = 'abc'; $imdb = 'defg';
if ($con = mysqli_connect($a,$b,$c,$d)) {
    if (mysqli_query($con,"DELETE FROM blah WHERE a = '{$imdb}'")){
        echo 'Deleted!';
        if (mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO foo (c,d) VALUES ('{$rt}','{$imdb}')")){
        echo 'Inserted after deletion!'
            if (mysqli_query(...)) {
                 if (mysqli_query(....)) {

                 }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Some of my programs have many queries in a row, each of which is dependent on the result of a previous query. However, creating error handling for every single query and making sure that the logic of the code stays the same (not to mention staying readable) throughout can be a somewhat tedious and error prone process.

I would like to know a bit more about what is going on behind the scenes when a query is sent, because it would help me a lot with some of my questions. Namely, is it really necessary to write `if (mysqli_query())` all the time for correct error handling, or is simply checking if the so-called 'master' connection exists enough?

That is, after I check `mysqli_connect()`, do I have to check every subsequent query within that connection to see if it went through (connection-wise, not logic-wise), or is it simply enough to check `mysqli_connect()` once, at the beginning of the program? It would sure make things a lot easier.

Also, while I'm looking at `mysqli_multi_query()` for more practical query management, I would prefer not to use it until I can fully understand the simpler query functions.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only few things for you to get it right

1. You have to distinguish an error from a query result. If your query depends on the *result* of the another one - it's all right to check the result. But if you want to check for the *error* - there are better ways.
2. In a properly written application a query error is a **highly exceptional** event, and there shouldn't be code written to handle it in place. It have to be done somewhere else.
3. mysqli can throw an `exception` in case of error, which is actually a Holy Grail you are looking for.

So, if you want to stop your code if one of queries failed, just set mysqli in exception mode and then pile your queries one after another.

```
<?php
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$con = mysqli_connect($a,$b,$c,$d);

$rt = 'abc'; $imdb = 'defg';
mysqli_query($con,"DELETE FROM ...");
mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO ...");
mysqli_query(...);
mysqli_query(...);
...
```

And two additional notes

- if you want to undo a previous query if following one failed, then use *transactions*
- you should NEVER write a query like you do, interpolating a variable directly into it. You ought to use prepared statements, substituting **every** variable with placeholder in the query.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That was just an example - I didn't want to litter the code with `mysqli_stmt_bind_param($cxn,'sssd',$r,$t)` and whatnot...

Comment: So, what would happen if your program was running on someone's computer, and during the middle of `mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO...");` the user's connection was destroyed. What would happen then?

Comment: it would behave almost exactly the same as with your nested ifs